# Is there a way to increase the visible dimesions of a mp4 video?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, libav

I recorded a video on the Kindle and transferred it to the Ubuntu laptop. The mp4 video claims to be 1080x1920 but it is small when run in VLC.

Running it in VLC with a crop of 2:21:1 is effective. However, I have not found a way to save it with these dimensions.

Most of the resources I've seen explain how to reduce video file sizes without compromising quality.

But is there a tool (avconv, handbrake, vlc, etc) which can increase the observable video dimensions of a file?

Comment: When you play it with `vlc` check the Video Resolution on Tools->Codec Information--> Codec... and welcome (Out) on SuperUser.